# Turning cards over after river

Tags: poker-strategy

The river card has been turned, I check, my opponent raises $500. I turn my cards over before I call or fold to see the reaction of my opponent.  His reaction causes me to call and I win the pot.  Is that allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Good question, because there is no clear answer. It depends mainly on the venue, tournament or cash, if there are more then two players at the time and most of these can vary in different casinos. Than even after all of this the rule if there is one is often informal or weakly enforced.

Just to be really clear turning your hand over with more then two players in a hand is simply not allowed, and is rude. And the players that do not understand the difference between head up and three or more players in a hand are usually the ones complaining about people showing cards head up.

Some players are of the thought if there are only two of you, what does it matter. I would suggest that most players generally feel this way. I think most dealers and floor people feel this way. So I suggest that the reason the rule is not enforced with any consistency or severity is because so many people do not see good reasoning behind enforcing the rule. Kind of no harm no foul kind of thing.

That is with cash games. Tournaments on the other hand almost always have the rule. And the rule is enforced, because tournaments tend to be much more terse with their rules and almost always have penalties for violating rules.